# How to parse mm.dd.yyyy with opening_hours.js?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, iso8601, date-parsing

I am using [opening_hours.js](https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js) in my project. Given the raw input data comes as:

> 03.09.2021-05.09.2021 Fr 14:00-22:00, Sa 12:00-22:00, Su 12:00-20:00

I there a way to configure the library/parser for the given input date format `dd.mm.yyyy`?

## Related

- https://openingh.ypid.de/evaluation_tool/
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Talk:Key:opening_hours

Comment: 46k rep... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear here. I search in the "related" websites for a configuration option - without success, though.

Answer (score 1):

[opening_hours.js](https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js) is for parsing opening hours from OpenStreetMap's [`opening_hours` tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours). `dd.mm.yyyy` is not a valid syntax for this tag according to its [specification](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours/specification) (for example, a month can only be specified via `Jan`, `Feb` and so on).

So I doubt that this is the correct library for your task.